# Hybrid MVC/web API ASP.NET Core application with interactive and non-interactive authentication for Microsoft Identity Platform

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, microsoft-identity-platform

I have an ASP.NET Core 7.0 application that has both MVC routes and web API routes that I'd like to secure behind Microsoft's Identity Platform. The MVC side of the application should be interactive, while the web API should be non-interactive.

I've been able to get either one or the other, but any attempts at doing either have not worked. My current implementation has the following in `Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Using JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme will force non-interactive via JWT bearer
var authenticationBuilder = builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

authenticationBuilder.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
authenticationBuilder.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

...

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

I've also tried to have my API controller use JWT for the auth scheme with the authorize attribute:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

But the API controller's route are still redirected to the interactive login.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this is a multi-authentication scheme issue. So we can define the scheme we used for API and MVC page, then when we visit view controller we won't get 401 error but redirect to sign in page when we haven't sign in, and when we visit API we will get 401 error but won't redirect to sign in.

I created a new .Net 7 Mvc application and also containing web api inside it. This is what I did and it worked for me.

Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));


builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
//app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

HomeController:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;
using WebAppMvcApiAad.Models;

namespace WebAppMvcApiAad.Controllers
{
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        
        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

And the API controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.Resource;

namespace WebAppMvcApiAad.Controllers
{
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [RequiredScope("Tiny.Read")]
    public class DataController : ControllerBase
    {
        public string Get() {
            return "hello";
        }
    }
}
```

appsetting.json:

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "tenant_id",
    "TenantId": "tenant_id",
    "ClientId": "aad_client_id",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "ClientSecret": "client_secret",
    "Audience": "api://aad_client_id"
  },
```